# Deno Property 'utime' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'. await Deno.utime(dest, statInfo.atime, statInfo.mtime);

Tags: deno

I am trying to use the standard deno fs module but the compiler complains without the `--unstable` flag.

```js
import { writeJson, readJson } from "https://deno.land/std/fs/mod.ts";

const json = await readJson("input.txt");
console.log(`JSON: ${JSON.stringify(json)}`);
await writeJson("input.txt", json);
```

My deno version:

```
deno 1.0.0-rc2
v8 8.4.300
typescript 3.8.3
```

I always get the same errors. They seem to be related to missing modules but I'm not sure what could be missing.

```
➜  deno-api denoa filetest.ts 
Compile file:///home/astone/source/deno-api/filetest.ts
error: TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'utime' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'.
    await Deno.utime(dest, statInfo.atime, statInfo.mtime);
               ~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std/fs/copy.ts:90:16

TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'utimeSync' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'.
    Deno.utimeSync(dest, statInfo.atime, statInfo.mtime);
         ~~~~~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std/fs/copy.ts:101:10

TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'symlink' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'.
  await Deno.symlink(originSrcFilePath, dest, type);
             ~~~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std/fs/copy.ts:114:14

TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'utime' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'.
    await Deno.utime(dest, statInfo.atime, statInfo.mtime);
               ~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std/fs/copy.ts:119:16

TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'symlinkSync' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'.
  Deno.symlinkSync(originSrcFilePath, dest, type);
       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std/fs/copy.ts:132:8

TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'utimeSync' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'.
    Deno.utimeSync(dest, statInfo.atime, statInfo.mtime);
         ~~~~~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std/fs/copy.ts:137:10

TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'utime' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'.
    await Deno.utime(dest, srcStatInfo.atime, srcStatInfo.mtime);
               ~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std/fs/copy.ts:157:16

TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'utimeSync' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'.
    Deno.utimeSync(dest, srcStatInfo.atime, srcStatInfo.mtime);
         ~~~~~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std/fs/copy.ts:185:10

TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'link' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'.
  await Deno.link(src, dest);
             ~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std/fs/ensure_link.ts:28:14

TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'linkSync' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'.
  Deno.linkSync(src, dest);
       ~~~~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std/fs/ensure_link.ts:52:8

TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'symlink' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'.
  await Deno.symlink(src, dest, srcFilePathType);
             ~~~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std/fs/ensure_symlink.ts:31:14

TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'symlinkSync' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'.
  Deno.symlinkSync(src, dest, srcFilePathType);
       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std/fs/ensure_symlink.ts:58:8

Found 12 errors.
```

If I only import the readJson module then I don't get errors.

```js
import { readJson } from "https://deno.land/std/fs/read_json.ts";
```

I tried using a tag build but I can't seem to figure out the tag for `1.0.0-rc2`. I tried `https://deno.land/std@0.50.0/fs/mod.ts`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Deno.utime` has [been marked unstable](https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/4955), which is the reason why you should use `--unstable` flag

There's also an open issue: [Property 'utime' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/5175) for this error.

Currently there are multiple [APIs which are behind the unstable flag](https://github.com/denoland/deno/blob/master/docs/runtime/stability.md).

> As of Deno 1.0.0, the Deno namespace APIs are stable. That means that
>   we will strive to make code working under 1.0.0 continue to work in
>   future versions.
>
> However, not all of Deno's features are ready for production yet.
>   Features which are not ready because they are still in draft phase are
>   locked behind the --unstable command line flag.

---

The files that are using `Deno.utime` are `copy.ts` & `ensure_symlink.ts` which is the reason why if you only load `read_json.ts` you don't get that error, and don't need the unstable flag.

---

The latest tag for `std/` is [`std/0.50.0`](https://github.com/denoland/deno/tags) but you can always reference the github repo directly to whatever commit or release tag you want.

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denoland/deno/{tag}/std/fs/read_json.ts
```

So you can use the following for your snippet:

```
import { readJson } from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denoland/deno/v1.0.0-rc2/std/fs/read_json.ts'
import { writeJson } from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denoland/deno/v1.0.0-rc2/std/fs/write_json.ts'
```

Comment: Thanks for the info this works. It is pretty weird that a standard library requires a special flag. I guess we can live with this because it's a release candidate...

Comment: Deno is still in its infancy, so a lot of changes are going on, there are multiple unstable methods yet.

Comment: Thank you I see. So excited for Deno!
https://github.com/denoland/deno/blob/master/docs/runtime/stability.md

Comment: So am I :). I'll add that link to the answer to help other users!